# Simple query but slow

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have the following query is slow in Mysql. I have a index for `date,close,sec` in table price_all. There are more than 100,000,000 rows in price_all table.

```
SELECT date, close FROM `price_all` where sec=? AND date>? order by date
```

EXPLAIN output

[image]

Comment: How fast do you think a query on a table with 100,000,000 rows should be?

Comment: Best to check the Explain Plan.

Comment: `100,000,000 rows + MySql == Slow`.. Yep I think your maths is correct :) The speed of that query will depend mainly on the indexes containing the `sec` and `date` fields

Comment: What are the actual indices on this table? Is it a compound on (date,close,sec) or are each indexed separately? What does the EXPLAIN plan say? @TrueBlueAussie is right... the index on sec and date matter a great deal here. Ideally you'd use a compound (aka multi-column) index on those two, most likely on (sec, date) (but ultimately that depends on the cardinality of sec vs date and whether or not your where filters will always contain both sec and date)

Comment: Thanks @evanv. I have a compound index on (sec,date) and another index on close.

Comment: What is EXPLAIN telling you? Put EXPLAIN EXTENDED in front of your query and execute it

Comment: @evanv, I just added explain in my original post. Please take a look.

Comment: How long is this query taking to run?

Comment: I think you have the right index on that table. You could technically add close, I guess, but I don't see any need. Looking at the explain output you posted, that should be pretty quick. So maybe you have some values for SEC for which a lot of values have to be sorted (try SELECT COUNT(*), sec FROM price_all GROUP BY sec ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5 and select some of the most frequently occurring sec values and use those in your EXPLAIN query)... but otherwise you'll need to share more info. BTW, what does "slow" mean to you?

Answer (score -1):

Dates are slow to sort by. Try

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date), date, close FROM `price_all` where sec=? AND date>? order by 1
```

Comment: "Dates are slow to sort by" -- what makes you say that?

Comment: @evanv is correct. Dates are stored as large integer values (e.g. the milliseconds since a specific start-date), so are *very fast* to sort.

Comment: I'm out of date then (a frequency occurrence these days)